# How to use middlewares when using scrapy runspider command?

Tags: scrapy

I know that we can configure middlewares in `settings.py` when we have a scrapy project.

I haven't started a scrapy project, and I use runspider command to run spider, but I want to use some middlewares. How to set it in the spider file?

Comment: To the close voters: this is a legitimate and useful question, please refrain the votes to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is, when you run a spider using `scrapy runspider my_file.py`, you can use the `-s` option to pass only simple scalar spider settings (like strings or integers). The problem is, the `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES` setting expects a dictionary, and there isn't a really straight-forward way to pass that through the command-line.

Currently, the only way I know to set SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES settings for a spider without a project is using custom spider settings, which is currently available <s>in [Scrapy from the code repo](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) (not officially released yet)</s> since [Scrapy 1.0](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/news.html#id4).

If you go that route, you can put your middlewares in a file `middlewares.py` and do:

```
import middlewares  # need this, or you get import error

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my-spider'

    custom_settings = {
        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'middlewares.SampleMiddleware': 500,
        }
    }

    ...
```

Alternatively, if you're putting the middleware class in the same file, you can use:

```
import scrapy

class SampleMiddleware(object):
    # your middleware code here
    ...


def fullname(o):
    return o.__module__ + "." + o.__name__


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my-spider'

    custom_settings = {
        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            fullname(SampleMiddleware): 500,
        }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I am trying to do use the same logic/setup to define an http proxy middleware as follows: `custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750
        }
    }` and then calling it in my request with `request.meta['proxy'] = "proxy-ip:proxy-port"
     yield request` but the spider toes not run and says: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 522, in isIPv6Address
    if '%' in addr:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable What am I doing wrong?
`

Comment: @user1991118 please ask a new question posting your spider code

Comment: I already did. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301465/scrapy-proxy-middleware-without-project