# scrapy proxy middleware without project

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy's runspider method to run a spider that I've setup and defined without a project. I am setting up my custom settings and Downloader Middlewares to define an http proxy middleware as follows:

`custom_settings = { 'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': { 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 750 } }`

and then calling it in my request with 
`request.meta['proxy'] = "proxy-ip:proxy-port"`
 
`yield request`

but the spider does not run and says: 

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 522, in isIPv6Address if '%' in addr: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging (not much logging going on in Scrapy, I'm afraid), I found that this problem can be caused by not specifying the scheme in the proxy address; i.e., Scrapy expects the proxy to be passed as a URI, so in your case, instead of:

```
request.meta['proxy'] = "proxy-ip:proxy-port"  # doesn't work
```

you want this:

```
request.meta['proxy'] = "http://proxy-ip:proxy-port"  # does work
```

(As far as I can make out, the `http` is just ignored, but without it the rest can't be parsed by `urlparse`).